# 紹介されているrunActionの種類のアニメーションを行いたいです

Tags: cocos2d-x

プログラム初心者の学生です。

こちらのサイトなどで紹介されているrunActionの種類のようなものがあります。
http://brbranch.jp/blog/201309/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x_animation2/

私は自分で作ったゲームのSpriteに 上記で紹介されていた
「波紋を広げる」アニメーションをつけたいのですが、
Cocos2d-x(Ver 3.3)に、プログラムを書いても動作が確認できませんでした。

あらかじめCocos2d-xには《CCRipple3D》などは用意されているように見えますが、
別でヘッダーファイルなどを用意しなければいけないのでしょうか？
何か特別な作業などする必要があるのでしょうか？教えてください。

Comment: 回答者が手元で再現できるようなコードを載せられますか? そうすると解決策が見つかりやすくなると思います。(質問は後から[edit]できます)

Answer (score 1):

同じくプログラミング勉強中の学生です。

Cocos2d-x v2 系まではこれで動作していたようでしたが、
v3 からRipple3D のアクションはNodeGrid でなければいけなくなったようです。
以下は実際に動作が確認できたコードです。

```
// スプライトを作成
Sprite *fish = Sprite::create("orangeFish.png");
fish->setPosition(Vec2(320,568));

// 波紋を広げるアニメーション作成
Ripple3D* action = Ripple3D::create(6, cocos2d::Size(150, 150), Vec2(640/2, 1136/2), 500, 7, 100);

// NodeGrid作成
NodeGrid *nodeGrid = NodeGrid::create();
nodeGrid->addChild(fish);
nodeGrid->runAction(action);

this->addChild(nodeGrid);
```

[image: Ripple3Dアニメーション]